# How do I configure my index.html with Systemsj to use an existing bundle?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, jspm, systemjs

I have a small TypeScript helloworld application that uses the aurelia.io framework from a bundle file and configured using SystemJS.  When I run my app, the compiled typescript version of my `helloworld.ts` throws an error which reads:

```
TypeError: define is not a function at System.register.execute
(http://localhost:9000/src/helloworld.js!eval:31:13) at t ...
```

Seems to me like the function `define` is in declared by SystemJS, so perhaps this is a configuration issue.  The framework seems to load fine, but I find it quite odd that the systemjs function is not recognized.

Here is my project hierarchy and my configuration files.  What am I doing wrong?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
./jspm_packages/...

./scripts/aurelia/aulrelia-bundle.js

./src/main.ts
./src/main.js (compiled ts)
./src/app.ts
./src/app.js (compiled ts)
./src/helloworld.ts
./src/helloworld.js (compiled ts)

./index.html
./config.js
```

I have installed jspm, and followed the prompts to create a default config.js files.  The only option I changed from default was to use babel as the transpiler.

My config.js looks like this:

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/",
  "transpiler": "babel",
  "babelOptions": {
    "optional": [
      "runtime"
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "*": "*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*.js"
  }
});

System.config({
  "map": {
    "babel": "npm:babel-core@5.5.6",
    "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@5.5.6",
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.15",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.10.1"
    },
    "npm:babel-runtime@5.5.6": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:core-js@0.9.15": {
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1",
      "systemjs-json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0"
    }
  }
});
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body aurelia-app>
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="message">Welcome...</div>
    </div>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
     System.config({
       "paths": {
         "*": "*.js"
       }
     });
     //Project uses bundles
     System.bundles["scripts/aurelia/aurelia-bundle"]=["aurelia-bootstrapper"];
     System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `helloword.ts` looks like this:

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class HelloWorld{

  @bindable hello="Hello!";

}
```

The full error:

```
TypeError: define is not a function at System.register.execute
(http://localhost:9000/src/helloworld.js!eval:31:13) at t
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:19798) at v
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:20180) at u 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:19856) at s
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:19737) at
http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:22064 at O
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:7439)
at K 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:7071) at y.7.y.when 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:10745) at v.7.v.run 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:9781) at a.3.a._drain 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:1740)
at 3.a.drain 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:1394) at MutationObserver.b 
(http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/es6-module-loader.js:7:3302)(anonymous function) @ aurelia-bundle.js:16334run @ aurelia-bundle.js:1602(anonymous
function) @ aurelia-bundle.js:1613module.exports @ aurelia-bundle.js:2906queue.(anonymous function) @ aurelia-bundle.js:3416run @ aurelia-bundle.js:3404listner @ aurelia-bundle.js:3408
```

Comment: have you tried traceur instead of babel? I haven't go into using TypeScript yet but I read that recently.

Comment: Turns out it was a transpilation issue. Thank you.

Comment: @MattMcCabe They both do the same thing, only Babel (6to5) has been around for longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let `jspm` create the `config.js` file automatically and don't modify it manually. You can then use [aurelia-cli](https://github.com/aurelia/cli) to automatically create your bundle based on what packages you've downloaded via `jspm` with something like:

aureliafile.js

```
var bundleConfig = {
    js: {
        "scripts/aurelia-bundle-latest": {
            modules: [
                'github:aurelia/*'
            ],
            options: {
                inject: true,
                minify: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This will automatically modify `config.js` to include the files needed for the bundle and where to find them at runtime when you run `aurelia bundle ---force` (the force is to overwrite previous bundle). After that, your `index.html` will look something like:

Index.html

```
<body aurelia-app="path/to/main">
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The transpiler was trying to interpret a comment I had in one of my source files in the form of `/* ... */` which was causing this error.  This was happening despite having the flag to omit comments.